# In a Typo3 site, which .htaccess do I modify to add content types?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, typo3

I'm making a site with a BigVideoJS panel, based on VideoJS. I am experiencing the common "Firefox won't play a HTML5 video" bug. If I load the page from a static file, it plays fine, but if I load it as localhost (or, for that matter, from the remote server), then I get the error:

`"HTTP "Content-Type" of "text/plain" is not supported. Load of media resource http://localhost:8888/video/video_name.webm failed.`

There are many [suggestions around the web](http://help.videojs.com/discussions/problems/2041-video-not-playing-on-firefox) to add some content types into the .htaccess in order to fix this problem, like so:

```
AddType video/webm .webm
AddType video/ogg .ogv
AddType video/mp4 .mp4
```

My question is, in the case of a Typo3 (6.0.8) CMS situation, is this still the correct way to add new content types? And if yes, which .htaccess should I add those lines to? This install (inherited from a previous developer) contains one in /www/ directory, one in the /domain-name/ directory, and one in the /site/ directory.

I've tried adding the lines above to the /site/ directory .htaccess and restarting apache- it didn't resolve the problem, Firefox is still not loading the video. Am I trying to solve the wrong problem, or am I doing it wrong?

**Edited to add:**

Would hosting the video on an external streaming site such as Vimeo solve this problem, if the .htaccess doesn't?

Comment: I'd start with opening the video's URL in Firefox with the [HttpFox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/httpfox/) add-on running to see what "Content-Type" HTTP header is being provided by the webserver. If you are using Chrome, I'm sure you can find an add-on that shows the same. Then you will know if the "Content-Type" is the problem or not.

Answer (score 0):

The .htaccess file you are looking for is the one in the dir that (among other things) contains the main entry point for that installation, index.php (may be a symlink), and the typo3conf directory. It will probably contain something like

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^typo3$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^typo3/.*$ - [L]
```

You can test if it's the right file by breaking it for a second (by adding incorrect code) and seeing if the website reacts. Or some more decent test.